# Outputting a value as a 4-byte unsigned integer in little endian form

Tags: integer, unsigned

I'm trying to output a value as a 4-byte unsigned integer (in little endian form) and am getting confused about something.

If I want to output the number 1 in this form does it appear as:

> 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000

OR

> 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

Similarly, if I wanted to output the number 256 would it take the form of:

> 11111111 00000001 00000000 00000000

I just need clarification. I've read some conflicting things from various places on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory is usually represented as a sequence of discrete bytes, so it doesn't make sense to talk about which bits are adjacent to each other. It's just a matter of display formatting. That said, it's traditional to display the LSB on the right, so in your example it would be

```
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

In hex, which is what you normally use when examining binaries, you'd get

```
01 00 00 00
```

Also, in your second example, you accidently represented 511, not 256. The correct bit representation for 256 is

```
00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Endianness effects the order of bytes in multibyte words, not the order of bits in a byte itself. So 1 is

```
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

and 256 is

```
00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000
```